# Creating instances of class using decorator design principle based on user input

Tags: java, design-patterns, user-input

At the moment I have executable code like this:

```
Sandwich sandwich_wTuna_wDoubleCheese = new Cheese(new Cheese(new Tuna(new Bread())));
```

For your better understanding, Sandwich is an abstract class that is extended by Bread and the SandwichDecorator. The sandwich decorator himself is again abstract and is extended by Cheese, Tuna, Tomatoes,.. you name it.

Now this works fine, however I have some bakeries that should sell these Sandwiches that were created using the decorator design principle.
How am I going to do this?

I want that I can do something like this:

```
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Cheese");
list.add("Cheese");
list.add("Tuna");
Sandwich sandwich_wTuna_wDoubleCheese = bakery1.SellBreads(list);
```

Sure I could pass in the instances already and do the decorating within the bakery function, but I hope there are other ways.

Have you an idea, how to solve this? Thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `switch` on `String` for every element in the `List` to create a layer of the sandwich decoration.

```
sandwich = switch (choice) {
    case "Cheese" -> new Cheese(sandwich);
    case "Tuna" -> new Tuna(sandwich);
    default -> throw UnknownSandwichChoice(choice);
};
```

You can do this for each element in the `List` with either recursion or iteration.

Comment: I think the word "ever" should be "every". Forgive me if I wrong

Answer (score 0):

This shows that the design pattern you chose doesn't match your problem.

First find out what you want to do with the objects, then choose a design pattern that matches these requirements.

You introduced (different) abstractions for compounds consisting of a partial sandwich with one additional layer (and gave these compounds misleading names hinting at the additional layer only).

But for ordering, you want abstractions for the layers themselves, and this doesn't exist in your model world.

So, I'd forget about your decorator pattern, and instead create `Sandwich` as a class having a list of layers, typically (but not necessarily?) starting with a `Bread` layer, then followed by other layers. Construction can then be done by either providing a list of layers in the constructor, or by calling an add(Layer) method on an existing sandwich.

Answer (score 0):

that looks like a job for a Factory :)

try something like this:

```
public interface IIngredient{}
public abstract class BaseIngredient : IIngredient
{
    private readonly IIngredient _inside;
    protected BaseIngredient(IIngredient inside)
    {
        _inside = inside;
    }
}

public class Tuna : BaseIngredient
{
    public Tuna(IIngredient inside) : base(inside)
    {
    }
}
public class Cheese : BaseIngredient
{
    public Cheese(IIngredient inside) : base(inside)
    {
    }
}
public class Bread : BaseIngredient
{
    public Bread(IIngredient inside) : base(inside)
    {
    }
}


public class IngredientFactory
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IIngredient, IIngredient>> _ctors;

    public IngredientFactory()
    {
        _ctors = new Dictionary<string, Func<IIngredient, IIngredient>>()
        {
            {"tuna", (i) => new Tuna(i)},
            {"cheese", (i) => new Cheese(i)},
            {"bread", (i) => new Bread(i)},
        };
    }

    public IIngredient Create(string name, IIngredient inside)
    {
        if(!_ctors.ContainsKey(name))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(name), "invalid ingredient");
        return _ctors[name](inside);
    }
}
```

Ingredient types are hard-coded in this case, but it would be quite easy to switch to a more dynamic approach. An option would be to scan the assemblies for types implementing the `IIngredient` interface.

Ingredient names can also follow a convention and match the lowercase version of the class.

Then all you have to do is something like this:

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
list.Add("Cheese");
list.Add("Cheese");
list.Add("Tuna");

IIngredient result = null;

var factory = new IngredientFactory();
foreach (var name in list)
{
    result = factory.Create(name, result);
}
```